# How to extract an ext from a filename having special chars in it-javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get a the extension from a filename. The filename could include special characters, "#,@,.,_,(),..etc)
ex:

```
var file1 = "fake.der"
var file2 = "fake.1.der"
var file3 = "fake_test.3.der"
```

NOw In the above case I want to extract only the ext "der" from every filename.
I tried:

```
file1.split(".")[1] //works fine
file2.split(".")[1] // gives me 1 -incorrect but file2.split(".")[2] gives correct result
file3.split(".")[1] //gives 3-incorrect.
```

since filename could vary, I dont kinda want to make it the `.split(".")[1]` static, by changing it to `.split(".")[2]` for other filenames and so on..
HOw can I make sure that regardless of how many dots present in the filename, I'll always get the extension only as o/p, is there a better appraoch?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slice ;)

```js
const fileName = "file.name.extension.der";

console.log(fileName.split('.').slice(-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match a dot, followed by non-dot characters, followed by the end of the string:

```js
function getExt(str) {
  const match = str.match(/\.([^.]+)$/);
  if (match) {
    return match[1];
  } else {
    return 'Not found';
  }
}

var file1 = "fake.der";
var file2 = "fake.1.der";
var file3 = "fake_test.3.der";
var file4 = "foobar";
[file1, file2, file3, file4].forEach(str => console.log(getExt(str)));
```

Note that you can't always be sure that an input string contains a well-formatted file extension, so make sure to handle those unexpected cases, as done above.

Answer (score 1):

With [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
function getExtension(file) {
  const index = file.lastIndexOf('.');
  return index === -1 ? '' : file.slice(index + 1);
}
```

This also handles the case if the string does not contain a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `\w` in a regular expression which matches any "word" character.  A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character. You should use `$` which starts marching from the back of the string

```
function ext(path) {
  let extension = path.match(/\w+$/)
  return extension ? extension[0].replace(".","") : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.split()` and some length calculations:

```js
var file1 = "fake.der";
var file2 = "fake.1.der";
var file3 = "fake_test.3.der";

function getExtension(name) {
    var nameArr = name.split(".");
    var fileExt = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];
    return fileExt;
}

console.log(getExtension(file1));
console.log(getExtension(file2));
console.log(getExtension(file3));
```